# On Signin page ,form action defined url is not submitted - Python,Django

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

When form defined on signin page is submitted for action="loginpost, it is not getting submitted .

```
Sign in Page is defined at this location : \_templates\pages\auth\singin.html

AUTH app tree structure : 

 admin.py
│   apps.py
│   models.py
│   serializers.py
│   urls.py  >> URL details URL 1 
│   views.py  >> Views.py 2 file
│   __init__.py

├───new_password
│   │   views.py
│
├───reset_password
│   │   views.py
│   │
├───signin
│   │   forms.py
│   │   views.py  >> sign1 
│
├───signup
│   │   views.py
│
`
URL1 ``
APP URL Defined as :
```

app_name = 'auth'
urlpatterns = [
path('signin', AuthSigninView.as_view(template_name = 'pages/auth/signin.html'), name='signin'),
path('login/post', LoginAPI.as_view(), name='loginpost'),
]

```
`

``
##Sign1 Content for singin page load #

class AuthSigninView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/auth/signin.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # A function to init the global layout. It is defined in _keenthemes/__init__.py file
        context = KTLayout.init(context)

        KTTheme.addJavascriptFile('js/custom/authentication/sign-in/general.js')

        # Define the layout for this module
        # _templates/layout/auth.html
        context.update({
            'layout': KTTheme.setLayout('auth.html', context),
        })
        
        return context

# HTML PAGE FORM
```

```
<form action={% url 'auth:loginpost' } role="form" method="POST">
        {%  csrf_token %}
        <!--begin::Input group--->
    <div class="fv-row mb-8">
        <!--begin::Email-->
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" autocomplete="off" class="form-control bg-transparent"/>
        <!--end::Email-->
    </div>

    <!--end::Input group--->
    <div class="fv-row mb-3">    
        <!--begin::Password-->
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control bg-transparent"/>
        <!--end::Password-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Input group--->

    <!--begin::Wrapper-->
    <div class="d-flex flex-stack flex-wrap gap-3 fs-base fw-semibold mb-8">
        <div></div>

        <!--begin::Link-->
        <a href="/reset-password" class="link-primary">
            Forgot Password ?
        </a>
        <!--end::Link-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Wrapper-->    

    <!--begin::Submit button-->
    <div class="d-grid mb-10">
        <button type="submit" value="OK" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" name="something"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Submit</button>
  
    </div>
    <!--end::Submit button-->
    </form>
```

```
## Views.py 2 having form submission view : 

from django.shortcuts import redirect,render
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import viewsets,status
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser,IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication,BasicAuthentication,SessionAuthentication
from .models import User
from .serializers import LoginSerializer
```

```
class LoginAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes =[SessionAuthentication,TokenAuthentication,BasicAuthentication]
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def get(self,request):
        print(' i m inside the get request here in view')
        return Response(' i m ok',status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self,request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        print(serializer)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return redirect('auth:signup')

## Serializer.py file defined for login user :
```

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from .models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed


class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username=serializers.CharField(max_length=60,min_length=5,write_only=True)
    password =serializers.CharField(max_length=60,min_length=5,write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username','password',)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username=attrs.get('username','')
        password=attrs.get('password','')
        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        #print('user defined is ',username,password)
        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid Username or Password.... Try Again')
        if not user.is_active:               
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Username is not active , disabled by admin')

        return { 'username' : username,'password': password  }
```

FORM is not getting submitted . It always print CSRF token with GET request in cmd console.

Need to ask a thing :

1. Can we define form submissions logic in a separate view for processing than from a view which render the singin html page .
2. loginpost is working fine while using the postman query .. but form is not getting submitted through signin html page .